# Why does percentage `max-width` behave differently on `img` compared to other elements like `div` (inside flex/grid container)?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

Below I have two versions of a simple `flex` container:

- The first one contains an `img`.
- The second one contains a `div`.

Both the `img` and `div` have exactly the same styles, which includes `max-width: 100%`.

For some reason, the behaviour of this percentage `max-width` style is inconsistent.

Why does the percentage `max-width` style behave differently on the `img` compared to the `div`?

Side note: the same happens when I use `display: grid` instead of `display: flex`.

```css
.wrapper {
    width: 300px;
    border: 1px solid;
}

.container {
    display: flex;
}

.img {
    width: 600px;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: lightGrey;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <h2>img</h2>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="content">
            <img class="img" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <h2>div</h2>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="content">
            <div class="img"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I understand I can make the `div` behave like the `img` by adding this style:

```
.content {
    min-width: 0;
}
```

However I am keen to understand why the behaviour is inconsistent in the first place.

Comment: they are not exactly the same. img is a *replaced element* which makes the difference here

Comment: Is there something in the spec that states that `max-width` should be calculated differently for replaced elements?

Comment: yes, refer to the duplicate for the details

Comment: ^ it may not look the same as yours at first glance but it's the same because in your case a flex item will have its width depend on it's content (like an inline-block, float, etc) so the same explanation apply here.